# How to remove account from ask ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

The https://askubuntu.com/help/deleting-account shows wrong information. I am looking for a real way to remove my account from this site.

Answer (score 14):

It's not wrong, there is no delete option for you because you voted and or posted, the next line is

> If you have voted or posted, please contact the Stack Exchange Team:
>
> Visit the [contact form](https://askubuntu.com/contact) and select 'I need to delete my user profile.'
>   After you contact us, the team will reach out with further
>   instructions.

Just click the contact form link and go to 'I need to delete my user profile.', this is how you remove your account.

Answer (score 4):

*User deletion is irreversible! By sending this request, your votes will be revoked, and all of your content will be made anonymous.*

As of January 30, 2022, you can easily delete your account by going to *Profile* → *Edit Profile* → *Navigation* → *Delete profile* → *Delete*

1. Click on your *Avatar* or *display icon* to enter [your profile page](https://askubuntu.com/users/current).
2. Click on the *Edit profile* button.
3. Go to the *Site Settings* column.
4. Select *Delete Profile*.
5. Accept the conditions and click on *Delete*.

[image: Self Delete]

Alternatively, you can quickly go to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/users/delete/current) and apply for deletion.

**Note**: If you have never made any posts from this profile and you have 101 or less reputation, it will be immediately deleted.
Otherwise, your profile will be scheduled for deletion in 24 hours. During that time, you can cancel the deletion request by visiting your profile and clicking the cancel link in the banner at the top. Otherwise, it will be deleted after 24 hours.

**N.B**: **Deletion of an account is not a complete deletion. To prevent *spammers* Stack Exchange stores [some information about the users even after the account deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375402/1085714).**

Reference: [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleting-account)

Comment: Note that the criteria for immediately deleting accounts on request are no longer "never posted or voted more than once" - those were changed 1.5 years ago and the help center [hasn't been updated yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360243/help-center-page-for-deleting-accounts-still-lists-old-criteria-for-deleting-the).